# Hosting WCF Service as Windows Service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, hosting, svc

I have created WCF service project. 
It has following content in SVC file.

```
    <%@ ServiceHost Service="Deepak.BusinessServices.Implementation.ApiImplementation"
      Factory="Deepak.BusinessServices.Implementation.CustomServiceHostFactory"%>
```

SVC reference

```
    http://localhost/DeepakGateway/Service.svc
```

Service is UP and WSDL generated. Now I want to host this service as Windows Service.
How can I do it?

I have created "Windows Service" Project ans have following code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (m_Host != null)
        {
            m_Host.Close();
        }
        Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/DeepakGateway/Service.svc");

        m_Host = new ServiceHost
        (typeof(?????? WHAT TO FILL HERE?), httpUrl);
        //Add a service endpoint
        m_Host.AddServiceEndpoint
        (typeof(?????? WHAT TO FILL HERE?), ), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
        //Enable metadata exchange
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        m_Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        //Start the Service
        m_Host.Open();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the type of the class that implements your service contract in the `ServiceHost` constructor, and type of the **service contract** in your `AddServiceEndpoint`

Assuming your **service implementation class** looks something like this:

```
namespace Deepak.BusinessServices.Implementation
{ 
    public class ApiImplementation : IApiImplementation
    {
       ....
    }
 }
```

then you need:

```
m_Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ApiImplementation), httpUrl);
m_Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IApiImplementation), new WSHttpBinding(), "");
```

- the **service host** needs to know what (concrete) type of service class to host
- the **endpoint** needs to know what **service contract** (interface) it exposes

Comment: There are many service contracts, which one i need to choose!